# Need a git command which gives only my source branch(working branch) changes

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to list the names of all files changed in a PR in Git/GitHub using powershell command.

I have tried various "git diff --name-only" commands which gives me the commit list between my sourcebranch(working branch) and target branch(Master).
But I need a command that will list ONLY the changed files in a PULL REQUEST.

Can some one please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

"git log --name-only" command will show the changed files in a branch. If you only want to check a certain commit, you may use "git show 123abc...(the commit ID) --name-only".

You may also use "git log --stat" command to get more detailed information about the changed files.

Comment: Notice the triple dot.

Comment: I' have tried above command, it is giving me all the different PR information which was submitted to the master. 
Can you please give me a command which gives the list of all files NAMES changed in a ONE particular PR.

Comment: For a particular PR, if you have already known its commit id, use git show and then plus this commit id, it should only list  this PR.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use the following command to list files that changed between any two commits `git diff --name-only` .

So if all of your branches originate with master, then you can use the below command to get the changes.

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only sourcebranchname $(git merge-base {sourcebranchname} {targetbranchname})
```

For example, I create a Pull request from branch1 to master, then the command should be like below.

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only branch1 $(git merge-base branch1 master)
```

Comment: Frank Wang-MSFT 
I' have tried above command, If changes to master were made after the PR was submitted, this command including those changes too. (I don't want master changes to be included).
Can you please give me a command which gives the list of all files changed in a one particular PR.

Comment: There is not a git command can show the PR changes files directly. I test the above command with your describe situation, but I don;t get the master changes. In addition, I tested this locally, and the PR branches are cut from master.